# Issue when trying to drop group from aws redshift cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

I'm trying to drop a group from my redshift cluster.

`drop group conform_main_prtest_admin_dev;`

This command give me the error,

```
ERROR: group "conform_main_prtest_admin_dev" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it Detail: privileges for default privileges on new relations belonging to user svc_prtest_ddl [ErrorId: 1-655f792d-1a94a4711cebe1ac035ca5ad]
```

I tried to find the default privileges using commands,

`SELECT * FROM pg_default_acl;`

Result,

| defacluser | defaclnamespace | defaclobjtype | defaclacl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 519 | 0 | r | {svc_prtest_ddl=arwdRxtDPA/svc_prtest_ddl,group conform_main_prtest_admin_dev=arwdRxtDPA/svc_prtest_ddl} |

I'm not able to revoke these default privileges. Can someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue after performing the actions specified in this AWS [document](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/redshift-user-cannot-be-dropped).

I generated the ddl to revoke default privileges to groups using the view provided in the doc. After executing the ddl I was able to drop the group.